# Proper way to detect motion from stream

Tags: python, motion, motion-detection

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to detect motion from a camera stream. I want to find the proper and most efficient way to do this since it will run on a raspberry pi.

**What I have done so far:**

I have taken frames from the camera converted ever frame from color to b/w resized the frame for easier processing and passed a Gaussian blur to soften the frames. The first frame is a keyframe

I then take the subsequent frames and calculate the absolute difference between the current frame and the keyframe. Once I have the difference between the two frames I calculate the average and push it to a list.

In this list (I call it a sliding window) I populate it with a set number of averages say 30. I then take the average of the list and calculate the average of the sliding window and divide by 255 (this is the average pixel value for the frames since they go from 0-255). If this average is > 1% there is motion else no motion.

After this I will repeat for 60 frames then I will set the key frame to the current frame and detect if there is motion again.

Here is my code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    keyFrame = None
    count = 0
    slidingWindow = []
    while(True):
        #capture frames and apply some blurs to later check absolute value
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frameSmall = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frameSmall, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)
        #if this is the beginning of a stream set the keyframe to the first frame
        if keyFrame is None:
            keyFrame = gray
        #show our frame
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        # compute the absolute difference between the current frame and
        frameDelta = cv2.absdiff(keyFrame, gray)
        slidingWindow.append(np.average(frameDelta))
        if np.average(slidingWindow)/255 > 0.01:
            if count % 5 == 0:
                print('motion detected')
        else:
            if count % 5 == 0:
                print('no motion')
        if count == 60:
            #reset keyframe after x frames
            keyFrame = gray
            count = 0
        del slidingWindow[0]

        count += 1
```

Is there a better way for me to approach this problem? Any other way I should be thinking about this problem?

Comment: I did a similiar thing recently. Have a look here: https://github.com/joesan/raspi-motion-detection

Comment: @sparkr Nice we followed the same tutorial :D. I see that you have this line: `cv2.accumulateWeighted(gray, avg, 0.5)` is this essentially what I am doing with the sliding window?